# Find all the numbers in the range [a, b] that are not in the given std::set S

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, set

Let `a` and `b` be integers, `a < b`. Given an `std::set<int> S` what is an efficient *and* elegant (preferably without explicit loops) way to find and store (into a `vector`) all the numbers from `[a, b]` that are not in `S`.

**Solution 1:**

```
 vector<int> v;
 for(int i = a; i <= b; ++i)
 {
     if(S.find(i) == S.end())
     {
        v.push_back(i);
     }         
}
```

**Solution 2:**

Push all the numbers from `a` to `b` into a `set` and use `std::set_difference`

Solution1 contains an explicit loop, and solution2 does not seem very efficient (at least in terms of memory). What would you suggest? I am looking for an elegant STL-ish (boost is also acceptible) idiomatic way to do this.

Comment: Homework?  Interview question?

Comment: @JohnDibling: Neither, just a practical tast that has arisen at my work

Comment: Had to write code for sample, so +1 from me. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do something like your solution #2. But instead of creating an actual container containing the range `[a,b]`, use [`boost::irange`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/irange.html), which is a virtual container for a numeric range. This way you have no explicit loops, it will run in linear time, and not take too much memory.

To make it even faster, make it cover only the relevant part of the set by using `lower_bound`/`upper_bound`:

```
auto abRange = boost::irange(a,b+1);
std::set_difference(abRange.begin(), abRange.end(), 
                    s.lower_bound(a), s.upper_bound(b), 
                    std::back_inserter(resultVector));
```

Or using `Boost.Range`'s `set_difference`:

```
boost::set_difference(boost::irange(a,b+1),
                      std::make_pair(s.lower_bound(a), s.upper_bound(b)),
                      std::back_inserter(resultVector));
```

Comment: And since you're using `boost::irange`, you could use `boost::range::set_difference` too.

Comment: @SteveJessop: If lower_bound and upper_bound are used, `boost::range::set_difference` would be useless

Comment: @Steve Jessop: agreed, I added an example.

Comment: @Armen: In this case the use is just that it saves the need to give the result of `irange` a name. So as interjay shows you get a one-liner (instead of two) that's a little shorter than with `std::set_difference`.

Comment: Thanks, interjay. Very elegant and efficient. Exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

The "set" in `set_intersection` doesn't mean `std::set` -- it simply means a logical set; a group of things.  If both collections are sorted, you can simply `set_intersection` the two in to a third container.

```
vector<int> common;
set_intersection(v.begin(), v.end(), s.begin(), s.end(), back_inserter(common));
```

EDIT:

Here is a complete example that illustrates the above.  This uses C++11 lambdas, but if you don't have C++11 or can't use lambdas, you can use functors in their stead.  Note the lack of explicit loops.

```
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

static const int numbers[] = {0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181};
static const size_t num_numbers = sizeof(numbers)/sizeof(numbers[0]);

int main()
{
    /*** GET THE SET ****/
    set<int> s(begin(numbers), end(numbers));
    //copy(&numbers[0], &numbers[num_numbers], inserter(s, s.begin()));

    /*** GET THE NUMBERS TO LOOK FOR **/
    int first = 5, last = 10;
    vector<int> targets;
    generate_n(back_inserter(targets), last-first, [&first]() -> int {
        return first++;
    });

    /*** FIND THE INTERSECTION ***/
    vector<int> common;
    set_intersection(s.begin(), s.end(), targets.begin(), targets.end(), back_inserter(common));

    /*** DUMP RESULTS ***/
    cout << "Intersecton of:\n\t";
    copy(s.begin(), s.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout,"\t"));
    cout << "\nwith:\n\t";
    copy(targets.begin(), targets.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout,"\t"));
    cout << "\n= = = = = = = =\n\t";
    copy(common.begin(), common.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout,"\t"));
    cout << "\n";

}
```

Output is:

```
Intersecton of:
        0       1       2       3       5       8       13      21      34
55      89      144     233     377     610     987     1597    2584    4181

with:
        5       6       7       8       9
= = = = = = = =
        5       8
```

Comment: May I recommend `set<int> s(numbers, numbers+num_numbers);` for C++03, and `set<int> s(begin(numbers), end(numbers));` for C++11?

Comment: You know, I think I like that better.  This was just an illustration, and I thought I'd throw in a couple extra illustrations as well, for educational purposes.

Comment: Fair enough. Questions that ask how to do something "elegantly" pretty much demand that people spend way too much time contrasting all the tools available :-)

Comment: For yet another tool available in C++11, consider `std::iota` to replace your `std::generate_n`/lambda: `std::vector<int> targets(last-first);  std::iota(begin(targets), end(targets), first);`

Comment: @SteveJessop: It's way too much time for the task at hand, but with a little luck, we all learn enough to more than save it over the next 20 years or so...

Comment: Using a static in a lambda like that is not a good idea, it will give wrong results if the code is executed more than once.

Answer (score 2):

Well the following avoids a loop but I'm not sure it's what you're after:

```
void inSet(int i, int b, vector<int>& v, set<int>& S)
{
   if(S.find(i) == S.end())
        v.push_back(i);

   if(i<b)
        inSet(i+1,b,v,S);
}

// ... snip
vector<int> v;
inSet(a,b,v,S);
```

Also, is there not a loop putting all the integers [a,b] into a std::set in your solution 2?

Comment: You can use `std::copy`.  I think OP is trying to avoid *explicit* loops, as they are "inelegant".

Comment: My answer was not entirely serious. The loop is still there but it's just not *explicit* any more.

Comment: It's clever, if a bit academic.  +1

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate from `S.lower_bound(a)` to `S.lower_bound(b)` and collect all the integers that you don't find:

```
auto end = S.lower_bound(b);
int seen = a;

for (auto it = S.lower_bound(a); it < end; ++it) {
   for (int i = seen+1; i < *it; ++i)
      v.push_back(i);
   seen = *it;
}
```

It contains an explicit loop, but somehow you'll have to look at all the integers in `[a,b]`.